# How to output my uploaded text in Shiny in R at the position of the screenshot?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to position a long text on the right side of this Shiny app, as shown on the screenshot below.

```
    library(quanteda)
    library(shiny)
    library(tm)
    library(tidytext)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinythemes)
    
    
    war <- readLines("war.txt")
    
    war_corpus <- corpus(war)
    
    sentences <- tokens(war_corpus,what="sentence")
    
    make_sentences <- function(word) {
      grep(word,sentences,value=TRUE)}
    
    make_sentences("prince")
    
    ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  mainPanel(
    img(src='image.jpg', align = "right"),
    
    #titlePanel(title=div(img(src="image.jpg"))),
    
    fluidRow(HTML("<strong> Search Bar")),
    #fluidRow(HTML(" <strong>Date: 06-29-2020</strong>") ),
    
    fluidRow(
      br(),
      p("User Name : ")),
    br(),
    br(),
    
    fluidRow(HTML("<strong>Enter a word.Click \"Next words\" after</strong>") ),
    fluidRow( p("\n") ),
    
    # Sidebar layout
    sidebarLayout(
      
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("inputString","Enter a word here",value = " "),
        submitButton("Next words")
      ),
      
      mainPanel(
        h4("Are you looking for this ?"),
        tags$style("#mytext {white-space: pre-line;}"),
        verbatimTextOutput("mytext")
        
      )
    )
  )))


    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$mytext <- renderPrint({
        
        sentences <- make_sentences(input$inputString)
        length(sentences)
        cat(paste0(1:length(sentences),"  ",sentences,sep= '\n'))
      })
    }
```

[image]
here is the rcloud link of the project to experiment with : https://rstudio.cloud/project/1497912

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use the Sidebar layout which allows only two columns, instead you should use the grid layout to position your elements where you want them, see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html.

You probably need something like this (not tested):

```
ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
      # content left 
    ),
    column(5,
      # content centre
    ),
    column(4,
      # content right
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: i tried it and I am getting the present "main panel" output as form of single line vertically :(

Comment: @d123 see edit.

Comment: i did the same thing and also tried "offset" to give space . gave me same output vertically

Comment: @d123 well then you must have a mistake somewhere :) You could try using the example from the Shiny documentation in order to start from a 3 columns layout which works, and then insert your elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the shiny application, open it in chrome - using google chrome inspector you find the css class titles and add custom css.